# HTML5 for .NET developers using Kendo UI ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html, kendo-ui

I have used kendo grid to show list of emails collected from the controller, then when user clicks on a grid row the email body is displayed in kendo editor, i want to edit the email on the editor and save the email body back to the database using web service. But to interact with c# code in the server side it is not that straight forward. We dont want to have too much Javascript code. Current code is like that

__*_*__ index.aspx

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.mailList)
        .Name("Grid")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:auto;font-size: medium;" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.MailId).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(p => p.From.Value).Width(200).Title("Sender");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Subject).Width(200);
            //columns.command(commands =>
            //{
            //    commands.destroy();
            //});

        }) 
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()

        .Events(events => events.Change("onChange")) 

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            //.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Index","Home"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                //The unique identifier (primary key) of the model is the ProductID property
                model.Id(p => p.MailId);

                // Declare a model field and optionally specify its default value (used when a new model instance is created)
                model.Field(p => p.Subject).DefaultValue("N/A");

                // Declare a model field and make it readonly
                model.Field(p => p.Sender).Editable(false);
            })                              

            .PageSize(5)          
            )
            .Selectable()

%>

function sendMailToController() {
       $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SendMail/",
            data: {
                emailID: mailID,
                emailBody: mailBody

            },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success) { 
                   alert("Operation Completed");
                } else {
                    alert("Operation Failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

__*_*___Controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            MailModel mailModelobj = new MailModel();
            mailModelobj.GetMailList();
            return View(mailModelobj);


        }

public JsonResult SendMail(Guid emailID, string emailBody)
        {
            MailModel mailModelObj = new MailModel();
            mailModelObj.body = emailBody;
            mailModelObj.mailID = emailID;
            var Result = mailModelObj.SendMail(mailModelObj);

            return Json(new { Success = true, Result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Problem is, it is not working for a long email body texts from editor. We dont like above way of communication.

We want to be in C# domain not too much in Javascript.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice to interact with server side from kendo ui controls (get the values from controller and set the values through the controller ?
2. Can you please explain with some little example like a submit button to submit the email body back to the server.
3. Is it possible to do Test Driven Development with kendo UI ? How or example will be very helpful.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, it is not working for a long email body texts from editor.
>   We dont like above way of communication.

Use POST instead of GET:

```
[HttPost]
public JsonResult SendMail(Guid emailID, string emailBody)
{
    ...
}


$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SendMail/",  (you should use Url.Action here)
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            emailID: mailID,
            emailBody: mailBody

        },
        cache: false,
        timeout: 10000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) { 
               alert("Operation Completed");
            } else {
                alert("Operation Failed");
            }
        }
    });
```

> What is the best practice to interact with server side from kendo ui
>   controls (get the values from controller and set the values through
>   the controller ?

From my experience, it's the good approach (using AJAX requests).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply..changing to POST it works :) Using ajax approach, is there any way to send a full object (mail object with several properties) instead of emailID, emailBody ?

Comment: @JohnSohn Yes, it's definitely possible to send a full object. See http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx for example.

Comment: Hi, i just saw that, now it can send long mail body with simple strings..but HTML formatted mail body is not working. No AJAX call is firing..